cannot use mergeTableCells ckeditor 5
I am using ckeditor 5 for a text area in a popup, my configuration file is as follows:
<script type="module">
    import {
        ClassicEditor,
        Autoformat,
        Bold,
        Italic,
        Underline,
        BlockQuote,
        Essentials,
        FindAndReplace,
        Font,
        Heading,
        Indent,
        IndentBlock,
        Link,
        List,
        Mention,
        Paragraph,
        PasteFromOffice,
        Table,
        TableColumnResize,
        TableToolbar,
        TextTransformation,
        HtmlEmbed,
        CodeBlock,
        RemoveFormat,
        Code,
        SpecialCharacters,
        HorizontalLine,
        PageBreak,
        TodoList,
        Strikethrough,
        Subscript,
        Superscript,
        Highlight,
        Alignment,  
        FileRepository,
        Image,
        ImageToolbar,
        ImageCaption,
        ImageStyle,
        PictureEditing,
        ImageUpload,
        BalloonToolbar 
    } from 'ckeditor5';

    // CustomUploadAdapter sử dụng hàm uploadFiles
    class MyUploadAdapter {
        constructor(loader) {
            this.loader = loader;
        }

        upload() {
            return this.loader.file
                .then(file => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        // Tạo một input ảo để lấy file từ loader
                        const filesInput = {
                            files: [file]
                        };
                        debugger
                        // Gọi hàm upload và xử lý kết quả
                        Utils.uploadFiles(filesInput)
                            .then(data => {
                                if (data.length > 0) {
                                    resolve({
                                        default: data // URL của ảnh đã được upload
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    reject('Upload failed');
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                reject(error);
                            });
                    });
                });
        }

        abort() {
            // Logic để hủy bỏ upload nếu cần
        }
    }

    // Plugin tùy chỉnh để sử dụng CustomUploadAdapter
    function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
        editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
            return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
        };
    }

        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#BlogContent'), {
                plugins: [
                    Autoformat,
                    BlockQuote,
                    Bold,
                    Essentials,
                    FindAndReplace,
                    Font,
                    Heading,
                    Indent,
                    IndentBlock,
                    Italic,
                    Link,
                    List,
                    Mention,
                    Paragraph,
                    PasteFromOffice,
                    Table,
                    TableColumnResize,
                    TableToolbar,
                    TextTransformation,
                    Underline,
                    HtmlEmbed,
                    CodeBlock,
                    RemoveFormat,
                    Code,
                    SpecialCharacters,
                    HorizontalLine,
                    PageBreak,
                    TodoList,
                    Strikethrough,
                    Subscript,
                    Superscript,
                    Highlight,
                    Alignment,
                    FileRepository,
                    MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin,
                    Image,
                    ImageToolbar,
                    ImageCaption,
                    ImageStyle,
                    PictureEditing,
                    ImageUpload,
                    BalloonToolbar
                ],
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', '|', '|',
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor',
                        'alignment', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', '|', 'insertTable', 'link', 'imageUpload',
                        {
                            label: 'Insert',
                            icon: 'plus',
                            items: ['highlight', 'blockQuote', 'mediaEmbed', 'codeBlock', 'htmlEmbed']
                        },
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                },
                image: {
                    toolbar: [
                        'imageStyle:inline',
                        'imageStyle:block',
                        'imageStyle:side',
                        '|',
                        'toggleImageCaption',
                        'imageTextAlternative',
                    ],
                },
                link: {
                    addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
                    defaultProtocol: 'https://',
                },
                list: {
                    properties: {
                        styles: true,
                        startIndex: true,
                        reversed: true
                    }
                },
                heading: {
                    options: [
                        { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                        { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                        { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                        { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                        { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                        { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                        { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
                    ]
                },
                table: {
                    contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells'],
                },
                alignment: {
                    options: ['left', 'center', 'right', 'justify']
                },
                fontSize: {
                    options: [
                        8,
                        10,
                        12,
                        14,
                        16,
                        18,
                        20,
                        'default',
                        'large',
                        'huge'
                    ]
                }
            })
            .then(editor => {
                window.editor = editor;
                const styleTag = document.querySelector('style');

                // Nếu thẻ <style> tồn tại
                if (styleTag) {
                    // Thêm dòng CSS mới vào nội dung của thẻ <style>
                    styleTag.textContent += `
                                              .ck-body-wrapper {
                                                           z-index: 10000;
                                              }
                                            `;
                } else {
                    // Nếu thẻ <style> không tồn tại, tạo một thẻ mới và thêm nó vào tài liệu
                    const style = document.createElement('style');
                    style.type = 'text/css';
                    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`
                                                                .ck-body-wrapper {
                                                                         z-index: 10000;
                                                                }
                                                              `));
                    document.head.appendChild(style);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
</script>

After running, it displays like this:
enter image description here
But when I press Merge cells, the escapeCssMeta command runs and gives the following error:
enter image description here
Can anyone help me fix this so I can merge the cells together?
Try to merge cells, it does not working

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
